# How to enter C-M-b in Emacs under a windows keyboard?

Tags: linux, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running Linux on a VM under Windows. When I am using Emacs on Linux, since my keyboard doesn't have the meta key, I will do my meta key command by pressing Esc, release it, and then press the subsequent letter key.

What if the command is Ctrl-Meta-b? My previous Esc way wouldn't work since it cancels the Ctrl. Any suggestion will be welcome. (Emacs and Linux noob here, so please don't laugh and be specific.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.  The escape keypress applies to the entire following key combination.

Answer (score 2):

Depends a little what your meta key is mapped to in Windows, in my (pretty "stock") Emacs 24.3 setup, "Alt" serves as the Meta key.

Comment: I'm sure there's plenty of scope for things to break, but certainly when I've run Emacs in a Linux VM hosted on Windows, I've had no problem using the `Alt` key as `Meta`. So `C-M-b` == `Ctrl + Alt + b`